# NodeJs setTimeout unique ID for clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a NodeJS app for scheduling tasks, the task is used to create a booking, that booking could be cancelled before the task is performed, there's a possibility of having hundred of thousands of tasks (e.g. 67 tasks created in one minute)

**The way i'm doing it is by calling this function:**

```
runOnDate = function (dateIn){
    console.log('scheduling')
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var booking = setTimeout(startBooking , (dateIn - now));

    //Lets try to catch the ID number of booking
    console.log(booking) // Shows [object Object]
    console.log(booking.timeoutID) // Shows undefined
}
```

My problem starts if i have to cancel one of this `setTimeout`, i know the `setTimeout` returns a `Number` for using it with `clearTimeout()` .

But i can't seem to get the number, is there a way to create a timer with an **unique ID** i can use for `clearTimeout()` or other way to call `clearTimeout` on a particular `setTimeout`?

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need the number, just do `clearTimeout(booking)`, and if you have many references use an array or object to store them.

Comment: Booking should be a number, not an object.  

http://jsfiddle.net/fz2WA/

Comment: you shouldn't use the return of `setTimeout` for anything else but `clearTimeout`

Answer (score 4):

`clearTimeout` should be passed whatever is returned from `setTimeout`. `node` does not return a `number` for its timer, instead it returns an `object`. So in this case you should be doing `clearTimeout(booking)` by passing it the object. In browsers it returns a number.

`setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` are part of the browser APIs and are not JS standards, so there is no requirement that they even be provided in Node, let alone that they have the same arguments/return values. In `node` timers result in an object because timers can have methods.

Given what you've said, I'd also suggest you consider using some kind of task queue rather than starting tons of timers. You would be better off maintaining a queue of tasks, and pulling things off of the queue as their start time arrives by just maintaining a single timer.